# JavaScript conflict with booking tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to insert a JavaScript booking tool on a website with WordPress. Since the support of the booking tool couldn't help my, I'll try it this way. I have inserted the code I got right here: http://engiadina-ftan.ch/buchungstool/
It's the following code which i've inserted in the WordPress backend text editor:

```
<script src='http://widgets.dirs21.de/QuickBook/Default.aspx?property_id=79690&rebook=true&submitMode=popup&SuppressJQuery=true' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

The support said I would need to add a suppress jQuery and add the Scripts for jQuery and jQuery UI (which I did, as you can see in the Firebug mode). However, the tool doesn't work. In the console I can see that there's a problem with the datepicker. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Use `$.noConflict()`

Comment: You mean like this? `<script $.noConflict(); src='http://widgets.dirs21.de/QuickBook/Default.aspx?property_id=79690&rebook=true&submitMode=popup&SuppressJQuery=true' type='text/javascript'></script>` ? I tried that, but it doesn't help...

Comment: @Irene Of course not directly inside the script tag name, but in between separate script tags. See the jQuery documentation on noConflict: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this in my header.php: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.noConflict();
        </script>` Still no function...